# Error while importing to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2007, 2013, error, import

I am importing a sitecollection from moss to sharepoint 2013. While importing a fatal error occurs and migration ends there. This is the stack trace of the exception:

```
FatalError: Value does not fall within the expected range.
[6/14/2013 12:05:36 PM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetServerRelativeUrlFromUrl(String fullOrRelativeUrl, Boolean includeQueryString, Boolean canonicalizeUrl)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.set_DocumentTemplate(String value)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ContentTypeSerializer.UpdateContentTypeMetaData(SPContentType sourceContentType, SPContentType targetContentType, String contentTypeXml, Boolean pushDownChanges, ImportObjectManager importObjectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ContentTypeSerializer.UpdateContentType(SPContentType sourceContentType, SPContentType targetContentType, String contentTypeXml, ImportObjectManager importObjectManager, Boolean& pushDownChanges)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ContentTypeSerializer.ProcessContentType(SPContentType sourceContentType, String contentTypeXml, ImportObjectManager importObjectManager, Boolean IsParentSystemObject, Boolean& needPushdown)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ContentTypeSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Migrating directly from MOSS to 2013 is not a supported upgrade path.
I would first upgrade the solution to 2010 before 2013 to follow [Microsoft's upgrade path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx)

[Here is a guide for this scenario](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx) from Technet, outlining the steps neccessary

Comment: I am using OOTB export\import apis and manually fixing packages for import to sharepoint 2013. It works fine for all the cases until I found this error.

Comment: Still, it is not a fully supported migration path